# Can a virus/malware spread through windows live id shared settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware, windows-live

I replaced a harddisk in a computer that was previously filled with viruses and malware and reinstalled windows 10 from scratch. When the owner set up their windows live account some settings like their old wallpaper came across. Could viruses or malware come across too? I do not use the windows live login myself, am unsure what it is called and cant find much detail on exactly what settings are shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Could viruses or malware come across too?

**Short answer**:

No, Programs (including Viruses or Malware) are **not** synced between Windows 10 Live Accounts.

**Longer answer**:

See below for details on what **is** shared.

---

#### What settings are shared?

> In Windows 10, the sync settings have been relocated to the Accounts
>   group and are now known as “Sync your settings”. Further, the number
>   of choices has been pared down to seven, which is far more manageable
>   to the average non-power user.
>
> [image]
>
> The first option is to simply turn off sync settings altogether. This
>   means essentially that your account on that particular computer, even
>   though it is a Microsoft account, is local. No changes you make to any
>   of the settings then on that particular Windows 10 computer will
>   replicated on other computers you log into with that same account.
>
> [image]
>
> Below the master sync switch are the individual sync settings. These
>   are the settings that will carry over from one computer to the other
>   that you log into with your Microsoft account.
>
> The first settings all are fairly self-explanatory. The “Theme”
>   setting will sync your color and background choices, meaning that if
>   you want each of your Windows 10 installations to have their own, this
>   needs to be off.
>
> Then you have your “Web browser settings”. The new default browser in
>   Windows 10 is the Edge browser, so this sync setting will apply to
>   that, be it bookmarks, themes, logins, and so forth.
>
> Finally, any passwords you store on one Windows 10 machine can be
>   synced to the others so you don’t have to always retype them all.
>
> [image]
>
> The second half of the settings deal with “Language preferences”,
>   which is useful if you use Windows multilingually.
>
> Similarly, if you use the “Ease of Access” sync settings, then
>   whatever adjustments you have made on one machine to its accessibility
>   will carry over to all your Windows machines.
>
> Finally, there’s the rather vague “Other Windows settings”, which we
>   can only assume means desktop items such as window accents, taskbar
>   position, and so on.
>
> [image]

Source [Understanding the New Sync Settings in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/222110/understanding-the-new-sync-settings-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

If the wallpaper file was infected, it can execute code on the new machine.  An infected image file is enough.   In addition, you have no idea what other settings a hacker might have made behind the scenes that would sync on the new machine.  It actually just happened to me.  Don’t take a chance.  It is hard enough keeping one machine secure you are better off keeping the machines separate.

Answer (score -1):

i must disagree i helped someone before that had cryptolocker on her pc she reinstalled windows cryptolocker installed back onto it while the hole harddrive was formatted and setup was from scratch

the solution was to sync only settings and turn everything else off then i asked her to reinstal windows the same way like before and cryptolocker was gone she could use sync agian normaly but just decided later to just turn it off knowing that it caused her pc to reinstall that program

so there is some legit reason to ask if viruses can pigy back onto the sync its not likely for a normal virus to be able to get onto the sync but i wont close out that more advanced malware/spyware/randsomware can get onto it regardless if its just settings its a file files can get infected

Comment: specific variations of cryptolocker are more worm then malware.